# Reuse Storyboard UIViewController in Stack Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

recently have been working on an application which involves a social media type navigation system.

I have created a user profile ViewController in Storyboard where the userID of the user to load is saved and then segues to the profile page.

```
//First Page after username is tapped - ID is saved and segues to profile page
if let id = userSelected["id"] as! String! {
                userID = id
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("userProfile", sender: self)
            }
```

On the profile page the viewDidLoad contains the following:

```
//Profile Page
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getUserWithID(userID)
        //proceeds to load user profile data and reloads table
    }
```

If you then click on another user (tagged on their profile, etc.) it loads the new users profile within the same ViewController as before (using the same segue). Everything works correctly up until here. When the user unwinds through the views and gets back to the previous user profile, the most recently loaded profile is displayed.

I'm not sure if some sort of cache needs to be implemented or something similar, any help is appreciated, if any more code needs to be provided just ask, thanks!

**Edit:** Added code

Comment: You need to provide some code if you want us to dig it with you

Comment: Added some extra code @Mayerz

Comment: Prove more code and a screen of the storyboard if you can.

Comment: It looks like you're referencing the last userId set every time.  Each time you set the userId, you lose the last userId, so your VC is populating with the last-set data.  Without more code, I can't tell if that's actually the problem, but it seems to be.